# What is the difference between 妥善 and 妥当?

Tags: word-choice, word

As with the case on many words in Mandarin, 妥善 and 妥当 both mean "appropriate" or "proper" in English.

However, what is the difference between these two words, and how can I use it properly?

Comment: bkrs: _妥善_ :appropriate; proper; well arranged; careful and skillful:
妥善安排 make appropriate arrangements
妥善办法 a well-arranged undertaking 我已经妥善安排了他的后事。 I've already made arrangements for his funeral.
妥当完善。
_妥当_ appropriate
proper
ready
well-thought-out; 
你认为怎么妥当就怎么办。 Do as you think proper.我已经把工作安排妥当。 I've made appropriate arrangements for the work.
1) 稳妥适当,
2) 稳重, users suggest studying jukuu's 100 samples for each to discover any difference in meaning.

Comment: since answer may to some extent depend on the context in which the adjective is to be used, could OP please provide context, anyhow some may claim meaning shade is influenced by that of 善/当.

Comment: readers learn that 妥善 is used for funeral arrangements by survivors,e.g. jukuu: 9.  The distribution of Edgar Snow's ashes according to his directions occurred later.
 按照埃德加·斯诺的遗愿，他的骨灰后来得到妥善的安放。

Comment: web search yields answers to this type of q:   http://www.hydcd.com/jyc/jy10661.htm  【妥善】稳妥完善【妥当】稳妥适当

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both '妥善' and '妥当' means  "appropriate" or "proper" .

There are minor difference:

'妥善' implies  "(satisfactorily) appropriate"

'妥当' implies "(correctly) appropriate"

Example:

- 對員工遣散有妥善安排 = There is a proper arrangement for severance. (everyone should be satisfied)
- 對員工遣散有妥当安排 = There is a proper arrangement for severance. (everything by the book without mistake)
- 妥善地佈防 = properly set up defensive positions (satisfactory on all accounts)
- 妥当地佈防 = properly set up defensive positions (follow all protocols correctly)

If someone said he will give you a 妥善的補償, he is trying to assure you that the compensation will be fair and satisfactory; If he said he will give you a 妥当的補償, it means you will get whatever you are entitled to. No more, no less.